# How to remove ' from a string

Tags: python

I need to remove ' from a string(url).

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import re

x = 0
while x <= 400:
    raw = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345"
    the_url = urllib.urlopen(raw)
    content = the_url.readlines()
    content = str(content)
    num = re.findall('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', content)
    num = str(num)
    num = num.translate(None, "[]")
    f = open("nothing.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(num) )
    f.close()
    raw = re.sub('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', num, raw)

    print raw
```

This is what it prints:

```
http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing='44827'
```

I need `44827` instead of `'44827'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns a list, which you then translate to a string. Don't do this.

You just need one value, so use `re.search()` instead:

```
num = re.search('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', content).group()
```

Even if you *did* want to use `re.findall()`, you only need the first value:

```
num = re.findall('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', content)
num = num[0]
```

If you are playing the challenge, be careful and *watch the return values carefully*. There is more to that challenge than just blindly following the numbers. Perhaps not all results begin with `the next nothing is`...

Your regular expression can be simplified to:

```
r'\d{5}'
```

`\d` matches the same characters as `[0-9]`, and the `{5}` tells the parser to match the preceding pattern 5 times exactly. Personally, I'd not limit the pattern to an exact number of digits; you can use `+` instead to match *at least one* digit instead:

```
r'\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace()` to replace all the single quotes:

```
>>> s="http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing='44827'"
>>> s = s.replace("'", '')
>>> s
'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=44827'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, the simplest of being str.replace. you can also go through each character in the line and if its a ' dont add it to a new line, otherwise add it. you can also do some fancy things tricks to get str.rstrip to work